# xslt: remove attribute when parent node has an attribute matching a pattern (filter out branch coverage on sonar for files mathcing a pattern)

Tags: xml, xslt, sonarqube, gcovr

I am producing coverage reports using gcovr for import into sonar.
This use this format  (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/):

```
<coverage version="1">
 <file path="src/hello.cpp">
  <lineToCover lineNumber="6" covered="true"/>
  <lineToCover lineNumber="7" covered="false" branchesToCover="2" coveredBranches="1"/>
 </file>
 <file path="test/helloTest.cpp">
  <lineToCover lineNumber="3" covered="true" branchesToCover="2" coveredBranches="1"/>
 </file>
</coverage>
```

I want to include line coverage for all files but I want to eliminate branch coverage for test code as it only the 'happy' branch is executed. Keeping line coverage in shows redundant code for tests that are never executed.
A bit like this issue - https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/issues/482

Basically I want to say:

- If the path attribute matches the pattern test/* then
- remove the branchesToCover and coveredBranches attributes from the children

So for the above the output would become:

```
<coverage version="1">
 <file path="src/hello.cpp">
  <lineToCover lineNumber="6" covered="true"/>
  <lineToCover lineNumber="7" covered="false" branchesToCover="2" coveredBranches="1"/>
 </file>
 <file path="test/helloTest.cpp">
  <lineToCover lineNumber="3" covered="true"/>
 </file>
</coverage>
```

This seems like an ideal candidate for XSLT. Unfortunately, this is a skill I have not yet acquired.

I have been able to work out how to remove the attributes for all elements but not how to restrict it to the case where the path attribute in the (parent) file element matches some criteria.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@branchesToCover"/>
   <xsl:template match="@coveredBranches"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would be helpful and educational if someone could explain how to do this or point me in the right direction.
I guess it could be some combinations of the answers to these kinds of question:

- [XSLT 1.0 : Remove element based on attribute of the element matching an attribute of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979412/xslt-1-0-remove-element-based-on-attribute-of-the-element-matching-an-attribut)
- [Filter Attributes Using XSLT based on Attribute Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699124/filter-attributes-using-xslt-based-on-attribute-names)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way this could be done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove branchesToCover attribute when file/@path starts with 'test' -->
  <xsl:template match="@branchesToCover[starts-with(ancestor::file/@path,'test')]"/>
  
  <!-- Remove coveredBranches attribute when file/@path starts with 'test' -->  
  <xsl:template match="@coveredBranches[starts-with(ancestor::file/@path,'test')]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVbj

Comment: Surely it should be sufficient to test once!

Comment: @michael.hor257k Not sure I get your comment?

Comment: [shrug] Do you now?

Comment: Both ways are equivalent in my view. Sometimes I'd rather have something easier to read than something compact.

Comment: They are not equivalent in my view because your way wastes processor time and electricity by testing the same thing twice.

Comment: I was going to accept this answer based on readability. I wonder if a clever processor could not remove the perceived inefficiency when compiling the template. Perhaps common sub-expression optimisation would be sufficient?

Comment: Also if using XML then wasting processor time and electricity is likely. Its hardly the most compact format.

Comment: I upvoted both answers, but in my opinion @michael.hor257k's answer is easier to read.

Comment: You may be right as the copy-of version doesn't need to use ancestor. Both things I have learned about from this question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file[starts-with(@path, 'test/')]/lineToCover">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@lineNumber | @covered"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option just for fun...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="file[starts-with(@path,'test/')]/lineToCover/@*[name()='branchesToCover' or name()='coveredBranches']"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```